# Non-linear Heat like equation in three dimensions

Tags: differential-geometry, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative, fluid-dynamics

Let $\textbf{A}_i\in M_2(\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty))$ (the set of 2x2 matrices with real entries in $\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)$) for $1\le i\le 3$ be invertable $(\det(\textbf{A}_i)\neq 0$), $\bigtriangleup : \mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ denote the Laplacian operator, and $\mu\in \mathbb{R}$ with $\mu > 0$. Is there a vector field $$\textbf{u}:\mathbb{R}^3\times [0,\infty)\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$$ such that $$\dfrac{\partial w_i}{\partial t}+ |\textbf{u}|~|\textbf{w}|\det(\textbf{A}_i) = \mu \bigtriangleup w_i,~~~~~ \textbf{w} = \textbf{curl(u)},~~~~~1\le i\le 3$$

These equations are to be solved for a given initial velocity $$\textbf{u}(x,0)  = \textbf{u}_0(x)$$ at time $t=0$ along with the bounded energy condition

$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}^{}{|\textbf{u}(x,t)|^2dx}<\epsilon,~~~~~~ \forall \epsilon > 0.$$

The scalar $\mu$ is called the kinetic 'viscosity' (a quantity that measures the friction of a fluid). These equations are to be solved for the velocity field $\textbf{u}(x,t)$.

Here $w_i$ denoted the $i^{th}$ component of $\textbf{w}$. Now if there is a solution, is it unique and how does the solution depend on the matrices $\textbf{A}_i$, in other words how does changing $\textbf{A}_i$ alter the solution.

One thing I see interesting is the nonlinear term appears related to $$|\textbf{u}\times \textbf{w}| = |\textbf{u}||\textbf{w}|\sin(\alpha)$$ where $\alpha$ is the angle between $\text{u}$ and $\textbf{w}$

Comment: What have you tried?  How did you encounter this problem?

Comment: Do you have any decay assumptions (e.g. $\vec{u}_0\to0$ at large $\vec{x}$)?

Comment: I should have said: please edit the answers to my questions into the problem.  As written, the question is likely to be closed for lack of context.

Comment: What about $\vec{\nabla}\times\vec{w}$: must that decay too?

Comment: there is no constraint on the curl of $\textbf{u}$. It is possible it blows up in finite time t>0. I will add context now

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/137195/discussion-between-mrpie-and-jacob-manaker).